# outlook customized folder's integer value for jacob.jar in java

Tags: java, outlook, jacob

I know, I can access using `Store.GetSearchFolders().Item("xxx")`. I want to get the integer value for that folder. Is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No object in Outlook (or MAPI) has an intrinsic integer index. You can have an entry id to use in Namespace.GetFolderFromID, or you can use the folder name and MAPIFolders.Item().